# Equation needing to be in a group by statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have been getting this error:

> Column 'dbo.MainDB.Packaging Quantity' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

This problem came up after I added the equation for Total and I have attempted to add aggregate functions to the equation, but it just gives me the wrong output if I add any.  Also, if I add it to the group by clause then it adds unnecessary groups, does anyone know a solution?

Code:

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(varchar,shipdate,101) AS Shipdate,
    ID, 
    [Last Name], 
    Address,
    SUM([Packaging Quantity]) AS Quantity,
    Size, 
    SUM(Cost) AS Price,
    ROUND(Size/[Packaging Quantity], 0) AS Total
FROM dbo.MainDB
WHERE 
    Shipdate BETWEEN '09/01/2019' AND '09/30/2019 11:59:59PM'
    AND Cost <> '0'
GROUP BY   
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, shipdate, 101),
    ID,
    [First Name],
    Address,
    Size
```

Comment: Also can't have [Last Name] in the select without aggregation or grouping.  Though I suspect the group by [First Name] maybe should be [Last Name]

Comment: You could to leave ```ROUND(Size/[Packaging Quantity], 0) AS Total``` out of the above query in a subselect and then bring it back in in the parent query.

Comment: Sample data and desired results are needed to understand what the calculation for `total` really should be.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is clear enough.

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(varchar,shipdate,101) AS Shipdate,
    ID, 
    [Last Name], 
    Address,
    SUM([Packaging Quantity]) AS Quantity,       -- aggregation on [Packaging Quantity]
    Size, 
    SUM(Cost) AS Price,
    ROUND(Size/[Packaging Quantity], 0) AS Total -- no aggregation on [Packaging Quantity]
FROM ...
```

You need an aggregate function in the second hilighted occurence of `[Packaging Quantity]`.Given the fact that you are `SUM`ing the first time, it would assume that you want to aggregate the same way in the other column, so:

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(varchar,shipdate,101) AS Shipdate,
    ID, 
    [Last Name], 
    Address,
    SUM([Packaging Quantity]) AS Quantity,
    Size, 
    SUM(Cost) AS Price,
    ROUND(Size/SUM([Packaging Quantity]), 0) AS Total
FROM ...
```